# ansible, stop a service on all host that belongs to a group

Tags: service, ansible, jinja2

I writing an ansible role. I would like to stop a services on all host that belongs to a group.

How to manage this usecase with ansible?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible Playbook will have scope for host group.

```
---
- hosts: host_group_name
```

Ansible role will have task for stopping service.

```
- name: stop service on host_group
  become: yes
    name: service_name
    state: stopped
```

Ansible adhoc command:

ansible host_group_name -i inventory -a "service service_name stop"

Answer (score 0):

Use a when condition something like below.

```
    when: inventory_hostname in  groups['groupname']
```